# Binding several buttons to individual items in an observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

If I have an ObservableCollection in one of my classes. In my code behind my view I have an object of this class and use it as the DataBinding

```
 this.DataContext = MyCustomClass;
```

in the xaml code of the view I want to bind several buttons to items in the Observable collection. Something like this:

```
<Button x:Name="Bid_Price_10" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding myObservableCollection[0].Price, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Padding="0"/>

 <Button x:Name="Bid_Price_11" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding myObservableCollection[1].Price, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  UseLayoutRounding="True" Padding="0"/>
```

At the moment this is not working, am I missing something ?

EDIT: Create full code to demo what I am trying to do:

So I have a Coffee class:

```
class Coffee
{
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

I have a drinks class that holds a list of coffees:

```
 class Drinks
{
    public List<Coffee> CoffeeList;

    public Drinks()
    {
        CoffeeList = new List<Coffee>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Coffee c = new Coffee();
            c.price = i;
            CoffeeList.Add(c);
        }

        this.startCoffeePriceUpdateThread();
    }

    private void UpdateCofffeePrice()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            foreach (var c in CoffeeList)
            {
                c.price++;
            }
        } 
    }

    public void startCoffeePriceUpdateThread()
    {

            Thread coffeeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateCofffeePrice));
            coffeeThread.Start();       
    }
}
```

my main window code behind:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Drinks ourDrinks = new Drinks();
        this.DataContext = ourDrinks;
    }
}
```

and my xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="193" Margin="77,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315">
  <Button x:Name="Button" Content="{Binding CoffeeList[0].Price}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="28"/>
</Grid>
```

So the problem is that I am not seeing anything in the button. At the moment I am not using INotifyPropertyChange as I have been advised it would not be needed.

Comment: It should work if myObservableCollection is a public property. If you want to bind a variable number of Buttons, use an ItemsControl.

Comment: yes its a public property

Comment: I have a fixed number of buttons, will it not work in the manner i set out ?

Comment: Is Price also a property?

Comment: Price is a property of the objects in the ObservableList

Comment: I can see the property change event firing but the content of the label is not changing, it should change automatically right ?

Comment: The Price property should fire the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event. Besides that, there doesn't seem to be any need that the collection is an ObservableCollection. Apparently it just contains a fixed number of elements, so could as well be an ordinary array or List.

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens suggested: if everything is fixed, you won't need `ObservableCollection` nor `PropertyChanged` notification. The following code should be sufficient:

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

public class myCustomClass
{
    public List<Stuff> myCollection { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public myCustomClass myCustomInstance = new myCustomClass();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myCustomInstance.myCollection = new List<Stuff>();
        myCustomInstance.myCollection.Add(new Stuff() { Price = "1200$" });
        myCustomInstance.myCollection.Add(new Stuff() { Price = "5.5$" });
        this.DataContext = myCustomInstance;
    }
}
```

And the simplified XAML

```
    <Button Content="{Binding myCollection[0].Price, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Content="{Binding myCollection[1].Price, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

*NB: I specified an instance of `myCustomClass` as the `DataContext`. If you really need to bind it to the class, let me know and I will update the code.*

Comment: first of all thanks for your work on this. I tried your way but I just cant see the content in the button. I can see that the list that the Datacontext is set correctly and the list is updating but no luck.

Comment: I checked again and everything is fine. Have you changed the name `myObservableCollection` to `myCollection`? Do your buttons have the
`myCustomInstance` as `DataContext`? Once more: in my example, everything needs to be define before defining `this.DataContext`. If you need to do it after initialization, we should switch to an `ObservableCollection` and implement `NotifyProperyChanged`.

Comment: I am binding to an instance of a class. In that class I have a list that holds objects of another custom class that has a property "Price". I have tried use List, ObservableCollection and BindingList as the dataContext. but no luck. FYI  the prices as constantly updating thats why I thought I would need to use INPC.

Comment: I'll update my answer. But basically, that's the reason why you always should put your complete testable code here. We cannot guess what you wrote and what you really want.

Comment: Yes of course. thought it would be something simple. I will code a demonstration of what I want to do and update the question.

Comment: Hi Bob, I just updated the question with full code sample